# ostream crash using aligned memory on heap?

Tags: c++, windows, sse, simd, memory-alignment

Here's a dummy code I have, testing aligned memory allocation on heap with "huge" values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <immintrin.h>

const double ln2per12 = std::log(2.0) / 12.0;

class ApproxExp
{
public:
    long step = 1000;
    long min = -48 * step;
    long max = 48 * step;
    long range = max - min;
    long numSteps = range + 1;

    __m128 v_value_float;

    float *approxFreqMuls_Float = static_cast<float*>(_mm_malloc(sizeof(float) * numSteps, 16));

    ApproxExp() {
        long inc = min;

        for (long i = 0; i < numSteps; i++, inc++) {
            double pitch = inc / (double)step;
            double refValue = pitch * ln2per12;

            v_value_float.m128_f32[i % 4] = (float)refValue;
            if (i % 4 == 3 || i == numSteps - 1) {
                _mm_store_ps(&approxFreqMuls_Float[i % 4 == 3 ? i - 3 : i - i % 4], v_value_float);
            }
        }

        std::cout << "oct       ";
    }
    ~ApproxExp() {
        _mm_free(approxFreqMuls_Float);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);
    std::cout << std::left;

    ApproxExp approxExp;

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute it, "sometimes" it breaks brutally (Release mode, `MSVC`), showing this:

[image]

I'm not able to locate the error, since I don't see any exception code. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing any use of an `ostream` in your code.  Can you include that?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I've a simple `std::cout << "oct       ";`. Once I call it, it crash (sometimes...)

Comment: `i % 4 == 3 ? i - 3 : i - i % 4` this looks very redundant, so I'm guessing that there's a typo in there somewhere...

Comment: Definitely looks like you have UB somewhere then.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler doesn't rap you over the knuckles for `i % 4 == 3 ? i - 3 : i - i % 4`. Disambiguating parentheses are the polite thing to do here: is it `(i % 4 == 3 ? i - 3 : i) - i % 4` or `i % 4 == 3 ? i - 3 : (i - i % 4)`?

Comment: Can you include a `main`? So that we can compile, run, and reproduce your error ourselves?

Comment: Nothing change. Even if I use `_mm_store_ps(&approxFreqMuls_Float[i % 4 == 3 ? (i - 3) : (i - i % 4)], v_value_float);` it crash "sometimes"

Comment: `#define _APPROX_EXP_` That's a reserved identifier. You should use another header guard.

Comment: I've included also the main

Comment: Have you verified that your array access is within 96001?

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. Post error messages as *text*.

Comment: Are you hoping the compiler is going to "see through" that ternary and unroll + vectorize the loop for you, as well as reusing the loop body for a cleanup special case?  I don't see why you wouldn't use `_mm_set1_ps` and vectorize it yourself.  As for the cleanup, I'd worry that the compiler would actually do the check inside the loop, so I'd be inclined to use a wrapper function that I could call inside the loop with one set of args, and outside with another set.

Comment: @PeterCordes this time, question is not about optimization, but instead why sometimes it crashes. I don't see any "casual" critical zone

Comment: @JesperJuhl I would, but I don't get any messages (as you can see). Only a throw...

Comment: Sure, but I wonder why you would have written that in the first place.  As the answer suggests, you might have got the indexing logic wrong here and be writing past the end of the array.  (Or feeding `_mm_store_ps`  an unaligned address?)  When you use the debugger, where exactly does it crash?  (Values of local variables and/or registers)

Comment: @PeterCordes when I debug it never crash: it seems simd are replaced

Comment: @markzzz And why is it you cannot copy the text of the dialog box into your question? It's text, isn't it? Even if you can't cut'n'paste it you could still write it by hand. It's not difficult; post text, not images. Text is searchable, images are not. Text is *in* the question, imagws are behind links that may die. Just write it down .

Comment: Running the same binary under a debugger makes it not crash?  And BTW, I forgot you were using MSVC: it never uses `movaps` for load/store; it uses `movups` even for `_mm_store_ps`, not `storeu`, so you wouldn't crash from unaligned even if that logic had been wrong (which it isn't.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, never crash!

Comment: @JesperJuhl which text? Do you see any information text from that dialog box? :O

Comment: @markzzz I see "foobar has triggered a breakpoint" - that's the *only* relevant information in the image - the rest of it is irrelevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl really thats a relevant information? Tell thats the application has triggered a breakpoint is a relevant information while asking "why" it has triggered an exception? Come on...

Comment: @markzzz Then why is the image there at all - kind of my point...

Comment: @JesperJuhl to proof I don't have any idea about whats going on. Of course if it tells to me what the error is I were on Google searching it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reach the last index and its remainder isn’t 3, writing 128 bits at index `i - i % 4` writes outside the array.
And then you’re in the wonderful land of undefined behaviour.